# Android Studio failed to launch

Tags: android, android-studio, launch

I am new to development am building my first app. As I am getting closer to completion of the project I will need Android Studio... I have installed but it simply fails to launch. I have searched my options on various sources.

Fixes I have already tried:

1. Added disable.android.first.run=true in the idea file
2. Did a clean installation
3. Installed the latest version of Java
4. Did all of the above again as Admin just in case
5. Set the JAVA_HOME and JAVA_JRE and cmd %echo% came back with the correct path

There is one thing I noticed. When deleting the Google folder in my Roaming the program runs again but once I pick "Do not import settings" then the program creates this folder but pops the error.

I would post the error message but the error window comes blank.

Thank you in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you trying?
 Did you tried archived version(older Version) of Studio?

Comment: I am trying the latest version. How far back do you suggest I should go in the versions when downloading from the archived ones?

Comment: I would recommend Android Studio 4.2.1.  Depends on your OS you can download it from here https://developer.android.com/studio/archive